# Stumped by OpenShift on RHEL 6.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems, openshift

http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_deployment_guide_comprehensive.html

Attempting to install Openshift Origin, I am on step 9.5 for RHEL 6.4.  I did find a bug about installing libcgroup-pam for RHEL 6.5, but have found nothing for 6.4.  I am hoping, not being a Rails, or Ruby expert that someone has a clue for me.

MCollective on the Node Host

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from Red Hat Subscription Management.
rhel-6-server-cf-tools-1-rpms                            | 2.8 kB     00:00
rhel-6-server-rhev-agent-rpms                            | 3.1 kB     00:00
rhel-6-server-rpms                                       | 3.7 kB     00:00
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openshift-origin-msg-node-mcollective.noarch 0:1.15.0-1.git.12.238a070.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem-openshift-origin-node for package: openshift-origin-msg-node-mcollective-1.15.0-1.git.12.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-rubygem-open4 for package: openshift-origin-msg-node-mcollective-1.15.0-1.git.12.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-facter for package: openshift-origin-msg-node-mcollective-1.15.0-1.git.12.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: openshift-origin-msg-common for package: openshift-origin-msg-node-mcollective-1.15.0-1.git.12.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mcollective for package: openshift-origin-msg-node-mcollective-1.15.0-1.git.12.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mcollective.noarch 0:2.2.3-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mcollective-common = 2.2.3-1.el6 for package: mcollective-2.2.3-1.el6.noarch
---> Package openshift-origin-msg-common.noarch 0:1.15.0-1.git.228.238a070.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-mcollective-common >= 2.2.3 for package: openshift-origin-msg-common-1.15.0-1.git.228.238a070.el6.noarch
---> Package ruby193-facter.x86_64 0:1.6.6-3.el6_3 will be installed
---> Package ruby193-rubygem-open4.noarch 0:1.3.0-2.el6_3 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-openshift-origin-node.noarch 0:1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(openshift-origin-common) for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(open4) for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-rubygem(safe_yaml) for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-rubygem(rspec) for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-rubygem(rest-client) for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-rubygem(parseconfig) for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-rubygem(mocha) for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-rubygem(commander) for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-ruby(selinux) for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: pam_openshift for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: openshift-origin-node-proxy for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mod_ssl for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mercurial for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: libselinux-python for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: libcgroup-pam for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: httpd for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: git for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 for package: git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.x86_64
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.15-29.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.2.15-29.el6_4 for package: httpd-2.2.15-29.el6_4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: apr-util-ldap for package: httpd-2.2.15-29.el6_4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libaprutil-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: httpd-2.2.15-29.el6_4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libapr-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: httpd-2.2.15-29.el6_4.x86_64
---> Package libselinux-python.x86_64 0:2.0.94-5.3.el6_4.1 will be installed
---> Package mcollective-common.noarch 0:2.2.3-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygems for package: mcollective-common-2.2.3-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(systemu) for package: mcollective-common-2.2.3-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(stomp) for package: mcollective-common-2.2.3-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: rubygem(json) for package: mcollective-common-2.2.3-1.el6.noarch
---> Package mercurial.x86_64 0:1.4-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package mod_ssl.x86_64 1:2.2.15-29.el6_4 will be installed
---> Package openshift-origin-node-proxy.noarch 0:1.15.1-1.git.0.ce0a2d8.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: nodejs-ws for package: openshift-origin-node-proxy-1.15.1-1.git.0.ce0a2d8.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: nodejs-supervisor for package: openshift-origin-node-proxy-1.15.1-1.git.0.ce0a2d8.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: nodejs-optimist for package: openshift-origin-node-proxy-1.15.1-1.git.0.ce0a2d8.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: nodejs-async for package: openshift-origin-node-proxy-1.15.1-1.git.0.ce0a2d8.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: nodejs for package: openshift-origin-node-proxy-1.15.1-1.git.0.ce0a2d8.el6.noarch
---> Package pam_openshift.x86_64 0:1.10.1-1.git.0.8dc3dc2.el6 will be installed
---> Package ruby193-mcollective-common.noarch 0:2.2.3-2.el6oso will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-rubygem(systemu) for package: ruby193-mcollective-common-2.2.3-2.el6oso.noarch
---> Package ruby193-ruby-selinux.x86_64 0:2.0.94-3.el6oso will be installed
---> Package ruby193-rubygem-commander.noarch 0:4.0.3-5.el6_3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-rubygem(highline) >= 1.5.0 for package: ruby193-rubygem-commander-4.0.3-5.el6_3.noarch
---> Package ruby193-rubygem-mocha.noarch 0:0.13.3-1.el6oso will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-rubygem(metaclass) < 0.1 for package: ruby193-rubygem-mocha-0.13.3-1.el6oso.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-rubygem(metaclass) >= 0.0.1 for package: ruby193-rubygem-mocha-0.13.3-1.el6oso.noarch
---> Package ruby193-rubygem-parseconfig.noarch 0:1.0.2-1.el6_4 will be installed
---> Package ruby193-rubygem-rest-client.noarch 0:1.6.1-2.el6_3 will be installed
---> Package ruby193-rubygem-rspec.noarch 0:2.11.0-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-rubygem(rspec-mocks) = 2.11.1 for package: ruby193-rubygem-rspec-2.11.0-2.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-rubygem(rspec-expectations) = 2.11.1 for package: ruby193-rubygem-rspec-2.11.0-2.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ruby193-rubygem(rspec-core) = 2.11.1 for package: ruby193-rubygem-rspec-2.11.0-2.el6.noarch
---> Package ruby193-rubygem-safe_yaml.noarch 0:0.9.1-1.el6oso will be installed
---> Package rubygem-open4.noarch 0:1.3.0-2.el6_2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygems for package: rubygem-open4-1.3.0-2.el6_2.noarch
---> Package rubygem-openshift-origin-common.noarch 0:1.15.1-1.git.0.85e5f83.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openshift-origin-util-scl for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-common-1.15.1-1.git.0.85e5f83.el6.noarch
---> Package rubygem-openshift-origin-node.noarch 0:1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcgroup-pam for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package apr.x86_64 0:1.3.9-5.el6_2 will be installed
---> Package apr-util.x86_64 0:1.3.9-3.el6_0.1 will be installed
---> Package apr-util-ldap.x86_64 0:1.3.9-3.el6_0.1 will be installed
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.2.15-29.el6_4 will be installed
---> Package mcollective-common.noarch 0:2.2.3-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygems for package: mcollective-common-2.2.3-1.el6.noarch
---> Package nodejs.x86_64 0:0.6.20-1.el6_3 will be installed
---> Package nodejs-async.noarch 0:0.1.16-1.el6_2 will be installed
---> Package nodejs-optimist.noarch 0:0.3.5-1.el6_3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: nodejs-wordwrap >= 0.0.2 for package: nodejs-optimist-0.3.5-1.el6_3.noarch
---> Package nodejs-supervisor.noarch 0:0.4.1-2.el6_3 will be installed
---> Package nodejs-ws.x86_64 0:0.4.22-4.el6oso will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: nodejs-commander >= 0.6 for package: nodejs-ws-0.4.22-4.el6oso.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nodejs-tinycolor for package: nodejs-ws-0.4.22-4.el6oso.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: nodejs-options for package: nodejs-ws-0.4.22-4.el6oso.x86_64
---> Package openshift-origin-util-scl.noarch 0:1.15.1-1.git.0.6e4e94b.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Error.noarch 1:0.17015-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Git.noarch 0:1.7.1-3.el6_4.1 will be installed
---> Package ruby193-rubygem-highline.noarch 0:1.6.16-1.el6oso will be installed
---> Package ruby193-rubygem-metaclass.noarch 0:0.0.1-8.el6 will be installed
---> Package ruby193-rubygem-rspec-core.noarch 0:2.11.1-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package ruby193-rubygem-rspec-expectations.noarch 0:2.11.1-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package ruby193-rubygem-rspec-mocks.noarch 0:2.11.1-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package ruby193-rubygem-systemu.noarch 0:2.5.2-2.el6_3 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-json.x86_64 0:1.7.3-2.el6_3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby(rubygems) for package: rubygem-json-1.7.3-2.el6_3.x86_64
---> Package rubygem-open4.noarch 0:1.3.0-2.el6_2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygems for package: rubygem-open4-1.3.0-2.el6_2.noarch
---> Package rubygem-openshift-origin-node.noarch 0:1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcgroup-pam for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
---> Package rubygem-stomp.noarch 0:1.2.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygems for package: rubygem-stomp-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Package rubygem-systemu.noarch 0:1.2.0-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby(rubygems) for package: rubygem-systemu-1.2.0-3.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mcollective-common.noarch 0:2.2.3-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygems for package: mcollective-common-2.2.3-1.el6.noarch
---> Package nodejs-commander.noarch 0:0.6.1-1.el6_3 will be installed
---> Package nodejs-options.noarch 0:0.0.3-1.el6_3 will be installed
---> Package nodejs-tinycolor.noarch 0:0.0.1-1.el6_3 will be installed
---> Package nodejs-wordwrap.noarch 0:0.0.2-1.el6_3 will be installed
---> Package rubygem-json.x86_64 0:1.7.3-2.el6_3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby(rubygems) for package: rubygem-json-1.7.3-2.el6_3.x86_64
---> Package rubygem-open4.noarch 0:1.3.0-2.el6_2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygems for package: rubygem-open4-1.3.0-2.el6_2.noarch
---> Package rubygem-openshift-origin-node.noarch 0:1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcgroup-pam for package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch
---> Package rubygem-stomp.noarch 0:1.2.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: rubygems for package: rubygem-stomp-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Package rubygem-systemu.noarch 0:1.2.0-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ruby(rubygems) for package: rubygem-systemu-1.2.0-3.el6.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: rubygem-openshift-origin-node-1.15.0-1.git.26.238a070.el6.noarch (openshift-origin)
           Requires: libcgroup-pam
Error: Package: mcollective-common-2.2.3-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: rubygems
Error: Package: rubygem-systemu-1.2.0-3.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: ruby(rubygems)
Error: Package: rubygem-json-1.7.3-2.el6_3.x86_64 (openshift-origin-deps)
           Requires: ruby(rubygems)
Error: Package: rubygem-open4-1.3.0-2.el6_2.noarch (openshift-origin-deps)
           Requires: rubygems
Error: Package: rubygem-stomp-1.2.2-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: rubygems
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem:
yum-config-manager --enable rhel-6-server-optional-rpms

Comment: However, becareful that you do not have a second version of ruby installed, as that will cause a headache.  Perform `gem list` followed by `yum list *rubygem*[gemnname]*` to make sure that you only have one version of a gem, and it matches the one from the ruby193 repository...